# Ansible local mode does not pick up variables from all

Tags: ansible

I'm unable to access the value of a variable defined in `group_vars/all` in a simple `local.yml' playbook.

Directory structure I have:

```
/group_vars
   /all
local.yml
```

Content of `group_vars/all`:

`key_name: bar`

Content of `local.yml`:

```
- name: Local example
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="Key is {{ key_name }}"
```

Here's how I run the playbook:

`ansible-playbook -i localhost, local.yml`

The error message:

```
PLAY: Local example *************************************************************

TASK [debug msg=Key is {{ key_name }}] ******************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "ERROR! the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'key_name' is undefined", "failed": true}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT **************************************************************

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug on the master branch, which is unstable:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11325